# Implementing override Base class Extjs.Base class to internationalization using extjs 6.6.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, internationalization, frontend, sencha-cmd

I'm creating a Extjs project where i want to implement a Internationalization system defining .json files that represent each of the available languages, i'm using extjs 6.6.0 version with modern toolkit only and the principal sources where i take like guide are https://www.sencha.com/blog/internationalization-localization-with-sencha-ext-js/ and [Saki’s blog post](https://extjs.eu/localization-of-ext-applications/), the problem is the "Additional resource" founded in the first link: "Ensuring compatibility with the Ext JS 6 Modern Toolkit. It has no “initComponent” function. Another option can be found in the “config” property and in the generation of the associated “apply” method.", so one of the contributor's comment offer a solution given in the next repository https://github.com/jnesislabs/extjs-remote-i18n. Defining the next features:

- A mixin extending Ext.mixin.Mashup that helps loading localization files before the application is initialized.
- An override of Ext.Base class, to call the setters of the specific attributes we want to translate during initializing of ExtJS components.

When i implement this solution, i got the next error in console while its building and navigator console:

[image: Console error]

[image: Error navigator console]

Given a specific line in the Base class:

[image: Base.js]

Please, anyone can help me solving this error.

Comment: It is better to post code than links to images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You didn't post what you actually changed...